# Failing to start Jupyter Notebook : 'does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address'

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I am not able to start the Jupyter Notebook (Installed using Anaconda 4.5.11) configured to run a remote VM (Redhat Enterprise Linux 6.x). The 'jupyter_notebook_config.py' has the following property configured:

> c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'

The error returned is the following:

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/arnab/conda_pkg/python-skl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 869, in _default_allow_remote
    addr = ipaddress.ip_address(self.ip)
  File "/opt/arnab/conda_pkg/python-skl/lib/python3.7/ipaddress.py", line 54, in ip_address
    address)
ValueError: '' does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems to be a bug ([link](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3946)) in Jupyter Notebook itself.

Changing the value of the property from '*' to '0.0.0.0' solved the problem:

> c.NotebookApp.ip = '0.0.0.0'

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround while leaving `c.NotebookApp.ip='*'` is to also set `c.NotebookApp.allow_remote_access=True`.